# Is there a clipboard manager/app with a searchable history/pasteboard?

Tags: macos, applications, copy-paste

So far I only know of [Clyppan](http://www.omh.cc/Clyppan-Clipboard-Manager-for-the-Mac/) and [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) but clyppan is only available as a paid app from the App Store and Alfred only offers its clipboard feature with a pay-for upgrade

Comment: To clarify: you're not just looking for a clipboard app, you're looking for a *free* alternative to either of those mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 1):

How about [Clip Menu](http://www.clipmenu.com/)?
This seems to cover all your requirements and is free.